# Android sdk platforms for windows and mac are same?

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I have android sdk updated in my windows machine. I need to shift to mac. Already I have android sdk installed for mac. Shall I copy those platforms folder from windows to mac(android-10, android-11..etc). will those be same for windows and mac or different?

Comment: jars will be same. scripts and native binaries wont match

Answer (score 1):

This will be Helpful to you.Check [here](http://www.talkandroid.com/guides/developer/android-sdk-install-guide/) .It is what you are looking for.

Comment: No i dont need this actually.. I'm not using os dependent android sdk tools.. I just need the sdk platforms to do Ant build.. I was searching for a solution whether I could copy those platforms from windows to mac machine since those folders contain only os independent files like xml and aidl.. Actually that worked.. I could copy those folders and "build" was successful.. I wanted to confirm from experts here.. tats it... Thanks for ur answer..:)

Comment: @nirav that is entirely different from what the OP is looking for, please read the question carefully and if you are not sure about the answer than better to post it as a  comment. [Link Only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) are not acceptable on SO